# Why is launchMode=singleInstance not recommended?

Tags: android, android-activity

It says in Android docs that setting activity's launchMode to `singleInstance` is not recommended. I don't understand their explanation:

> The other modes — singleTask and singleInstance — are not appropriate for most applications, since they result in an interaction model that is likely to be unfamiliar to users and is very different from most other applications.

My question is: How would it be appropriate for most applications for an activity to launch in multiple instances? Why is this the default behavior?

I just lost an hour wondering why my activity slows down my phone and then I found out that multiple instances of it were being created by clicking on a notification icon. An easy way to solve this was to set the activity to `singleInstance` instead of `singleTop`, but it's not recommended and I don't understand why (and thus don't understand whether I can disregard the recommendation).

Comment: Yes I want to know as well. There's a lot of talk about it being bad, but not to why and how to achieve what we want in other ways...